# SQL Return top 10 distinct on a table, rather than top ten of all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have simple database set up 3 tables, a central product repository (Product), a list of suppliers and what products from that repository that they supply (Supplier_Product) and a list of shops and what products they stock from the repository (Site_Product).

I need to return for pagination **10 unique** products at a time, and any additional Supplier rows and Site rows as a result of the joins. I got as far as the below query, which returns 10 products, but they obviously aren't unique as you can have product 1 from supplier 1 and product 1 from supplier 2 included in the result set.

The @Supplier_Id, @Site_Id and @Search_Term are used to filter the result set.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking to return 10 rows in the result set, but 10 products - and their relevant supplier / site info additionally as duplicate product rows.

I hope that makes sense.

```
@Current_Page INT,
@Items_Per_Page INT = 10,
@Supplier_Id INT = NULL,
@Site_Id INT = NULL,
@Search_Term NVARCHAR(128) = NULL

SELECT P.Container_Noun, P.Open_Noun, P.Packaged, P.Product_Id, P.Product_Name, P.Quantity_Per_Package, P.Volume
SUP.Price, SUP.Supplier_Id, SUP.Supplier_Name,
SP.Site_Id, SP.Site_Name
FROM Product P
LEFT JOIN Supplier_Product SUP ON P.Product_Id = SUP.Product_Id
LEFT JOIN Site_Product SP ON P.Product_Id = SP.Product_Id
WHERE 
    (SUP.Supplier_Id = @Supplier_Id OR @Supplier_Id IS NULL) AND
    (SP.Site_Id = @Site_Id OR @Site_Id IS NULL) AND
    (P.Product_Name LIKE ('%' + @Search_Term + '%') OR @Search_Term IS NULL)
ORDER BY P.Product_Name ASC
OFFSET @Items_Per_Page *  (@Current_Page - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Items_Per_Page ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: So if you have Product 1 with multiple suppliers and multiple site_products, how would you define which one of them is relevant to Product 1?

Comment: They are all relevant. I'd like to return them all, but only for the first 10 products ordered by product alphabetically, I know there will be duplicate products, I want them all but only for the first 10 products in the condition.

Comment: You could use nested query to get top 10 Products, and use that to join to rest of the tables.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about implementing that, when I need to also filter based on supplier and site.

Comment: I am not sure which SQL are you using, OFFSET ROWS and FETCH NEXT ROWS are not for MS-SQL, is it MySql?

Comment: @GSazheniuk i just tried to make the query, using DISTINCT TOP 10 from a subquery INNER JOIN does the trick for the first 10, but i'm not sure how to get the next 10, and the next, etc

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hope this works, as I do not have same tables as you are using.

Let me know if you get any errors and I will try to help you.

```
@Current_Page INT,
@Items_Per_Page INT = 10,
@Supplier_Id INT = NULL,
@Site_Id INT = NULL,
@Search_Term NVARCHAR(128) = NULL

with cte as (
    select distinct Product_Id
    FROM Product P
    LEFT JOIN Supplier_Product SUP ON P.Product_Id = SUP.Product_Id
    LEFT JOIN Site_Product SP ON P.Product_Id = SP.Product_Id
    WHERE 
        (SUP.Supplier_Id = @Supplier_Id OR @Supplier_Id IS NULL) AND
        (SP.Site_Id = @Site_Id OR @Site_Id IS NULL) AND
        (P.Product_Name LIKE ('%' + @Search_Term + '%') OR @Search_Term IS NULL)
    )

select P.Container_Noun, P.Open_Noun, P.Packaged, P.Product_Id, P.Product_Name, P.Quantity_Per_Package, P.Volume
SUP.Price, SUP.Supplier_Id, SUP.Supplier_Name,
SP.Site_Id, SP.Site_Name
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN (select Product_ID from cte ORDER BY Product_Id OFFSET @Items_Per_Page *  (@Current_Page - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @Items_Per_Page ROWS ONLY) PF ON P.Product_Id = PF.Product_Id
LEFT JOIN Supplier_Product SUP ON P.Product_Id = SUP.Product_Id
LEFT JOIN Site_Product SP ON P.Product_Id = SP.Product_Id
WHERE 
    (SUP.Supplier_Id = @Supplier_Id OR @Supplier_Id IS NULL) AND
    (SP.Site_Id = @Site_Id OR @Site_Id IS NULL) AND
    (P.Product_Name LIKE ('%' + @Search_Term + '%') OR @Search_Term IS NULL)
```

So the trick here is to get 10 distinct Product_Id's first, and then use them to filter results in your original query.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've just left work but I'll give this a whirl first thing tomorrow :).

Comment: Couldn't let this lie in the end so had a go back at home and it works a charm. I'd upvote more if I could!